# Converting an FIR Filter Model to a State Space Model for Kalman Filtering

Tags: finite-impulse-response, kalman-filters, state-space

I want to try and determine the true value of a quantity $\alpha[k]$ from observations of a related quantity $\vartheta[k]$ using a Kalman filter. The observations are of the following FIR filter form:

$$ \alpha[k] = \frac{1}{h} \sum_{n=0}^{N}  c_{n} \vartheta[k - nh]  + w[k]$$

where $w[k] \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2})$ and the $c_{n}$ are known ahead of time, and so is $h$.

I want to put this into a state space model in order to process it with a Kalman filter assuming additive process noise. To start the conversion, I can put it in transfer function form:

$$ \alpha[k] = \frac{1}{h} \sum_{n=0}^{N}  c_{n} z^{-n} \vartheta[k]  $$
$$ \frac{\alpha[k]}{\vartheta[k]} = \sum_{n=0}^{N}  \tilde{c}_{n} z^{-n}$$

where $\tilde{c}_{n} = \frac{c_{n}}{h}$.

This is where I get stuck. I am not sure what to do -- which canonical form should I use? Should I even use one? Where does the noise term go anyway?

---

This answer gives the link to all the forms, and a general idea:

- [$N$ point moving average filters in state space](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34532/n-point-moving-average-filters-in-state-space)

However my model is slightly different. Other answers that may be helpful, but are confusing to me:

- [State Space representation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22985/state-space-representation)
- [Doubt in state space representation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22028/doubt-in-state-space-representation)

---

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at Simon Haykin_Adaptive Filter Theory, where he shows Kalman filters for FIR process equations. Derivation is due Goddard.